# Select where Join is Null

Tags: sql, firebird

I have two tables one has items and the second has the stock.
I want to select items where there is no stock available.
In that case there is no data in the second table.

Table 1

```
ID  Item
01  Car
02  Bike
03  Motorbike
```

Table 2

```
ID  Amount
01  1
02  -1
```

So item 03 is currently not on stock.

My SQL looks like this

```
SELECT
  ITEM.ITEMNR,
  LAGERBESTAND.AMOUNT
FROM
  ITEM
INNER JOIN STOCKAMOUNT ON STOCKAMOUNT.ITEMLFDNR = ITEM.LFDNR
GROUP BY
  ITEM.ITEMNR,
  STOCKAMOUNT.AMOUNT
HAVING
  STOCKAMOUNT.AMOUNT = 0
```

Of cause "having stock amount = 0" does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You  need a left outer join, an inner join will only return rows where the join condition is met.

I do not believe you need grouping for this.

Comment: Yes, thats right I had grouping because I was looking for numbers before. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

This works by using a left join.

```
SELECT
  ITEM.ITEMNR,
  coalesce(STOCKAMOUNT.AMOUNT,0) amount
FROM ITEM
LEFT JOIN STOCKAMOUNT 
ON STOCKAMOUNT.ITEMLFDNR = ITEM.LFDNR
WHERE STOCKAMOUNT.ITEMLFDNR IS NULL
```